# Reading Image in Go

Tags: image, go

```
func (sticky *Sticky) DrawImage(W, H int) (img *image, err error) {

    myImage := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 10, 25))
    myImage.Pix[0] = 55 // 1st pixel red
    myImage.Pix[1] = 155 // 1st pixel green
    return myImage ,nil
}
```

I am creating an image. I want to read the existing Image and return in this Function. How I can I do that?

Comment: Read an existing image from where?

Comment: from Image in the Directory

Answer (score 12):

Something like this:

```
func getImageFromFilePath(filePath string) (image.Image, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    image, _, err := image.Decode(f)
    return image, err
}
```

references

- https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Decode
- https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open

Comment: Don't forget to import "image", "image/png" and "image/jpeg". This way:
`import ( "image"
 _ "image/jpeg"
 _ "image/png"
)`

Comment: @LuisCabreraBenito that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "image"
  "image/png"
  "os"
)

func main() {
  // Read image from file that already exists
  existingImageFile, err := os.Open("test.png")
  if err != nil {
    // Handle error
  } 

  defer existingImageFile.Close()

  // Calling the generic image.Decode() will tell give us the data
  // and type of image it is as a string. We expect "png"
  imageData, imageType, err := image.Decode(existingImageFile)
  if err != nil {
    // Handle error
  }
  fmt.Println(imageData)
  fmt.Println(imageType)

  // We only need this because we already read from the file
  // We have to reset the file pointer back to beginning
  existingImageFile.Seek(0, 0)

  // Alternatively, since we know it is a png already
  // we can call png.Decode() directly
  loadedImage, err := png.Decode(existingImageFile)
  if err != nil {
    // Handle error
    }
  fmt.Println(loadedImage)
 }
```

references

- https://www.devdungeon.com/content/working-images-go